# Need help selecting new .net framework to create a very thin RESTful service

Tags: asp.net, rest

My team is building a new application architecture where the bulk of our logic and processing is going to be on the client using Angular.js.

Our limitation is our server, specifically we have no access to our web-server and stuck with currently only having the ability to use .net/IIS.  Our server is configured with .net 4.0, although I may be able to push for an upgrade to 4.5.

Our last project we created a WCF4 configure-less setup to create our RESTful services.  This solution was workable but I was hoping there might be some better frameworks/APIs available now to set up the lightest possible .net server.

We focus primarily on our javascript so we have fallen off in our .net knowledge, so what is the current "best" or most used .net RESTful service solutions out there?

Comment: Take a look at ASP.NET Web API -  http://www.asp.net/web-api - built using MVC it's super lightweight and is developed for just your purpose. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at ServiceStack : http://www.servicestack.net/

I've used it for a few projects and I can say that you can get up and running very quickly, especially if you start with one of the tutorials or example packages (of which there are plenty).  It's plugin-based architecture means you can buy in to as many or as few of the built-in features that it has, including authentication, authorization, and session management.  It also "plays nice" with MVC, so if you have controllers that also want to use features, such as the built-in authentication / authorization and session management features, then it's a snap.

It was built with efficiency and speed in mind.  It uses the best of the best when it comes to third-party libraries that it uses.  Everything is well thought-out and planned.

Comment: Thanks this looks like a good fit based on our needs, gonna check it out further

Answer (score 2):

Asp.net's [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) is the latest and greatest that Microsoft itself offers in building simple REST services. You can leverage the simple-but-extensible routing structure of ASP.NET MVC, and define your services using simple MVC-style controller actions that return plain old C# objects, which get serialized into JSON results.

I can't speak specifically to the "lightweight"-ness of Web API: it's likely that ServiceStack would perform better.  But in terms of keeping simple code, but still having the flexibility to do more advanced things when you need to, Web API has a lot to offer.

Comment: That's an interesting claim. Can you show me an example where WebApi is more flexible or better at keeping the code simple or how it's more lightweight than ServiceStack? Interested to see what metrics you're using to form these opinions.

Comment: @mythz: I didn't intend to imply that Web API is better than ServiceStack in these ways: I haven't tried ServiceStack. I just said that it has a lot to offer in these areas, even though it's likely that ServiceStack would perform better (based on Eli's assertion that it was "built with efficiency and speed in mind"--I don't have any data to back up that "claim" either).

Comment: ok no worries, just sounded like you've evaluated both and found Web API to be simpler - which is something I'd be curious to learn about how or why.

Comment: FYI here's a list of some [real-world performance comparisons](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Real-world-performance) from people who've evaluated different frameworks have had.